# How to read input from a file using ANTLRInputStream?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I tried many examples out there in web
but couldn't find any working example.

> So please provide one working example of How to read input from a file
>   using ANTLRInputStream

So that I can understand easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried and explain what went wrong?

Comment: Yah sure. Sorry about that.

grammar Exp;

/* This will be the entry point of our parser. */
eval
    :    additionExp
    ;

additionExp
    :    multiplyExp 
         ( '+' multiplyExp 
         | '-' multiplyExp
         )* 
    ;

/* Multiplication and division have a higher precedence. */
multiplyExp
    :    atomExp
         ( '*' atomExp 
         | '/' atomExp
         )* 
    ;

atomExp
    :    Number
    |    '(' additionExp ')'
    ;

Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') /*{$channel=HIDDEN;}*/
    ;

Comment: Kindly have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414352/taking-input-from-file-with-antlr

Answer (score 5):

It's really no more complicated than passing a standard FileInputStream to ANTLRInputStream.

From the documentation you can see that ANTLRInputStrean is pretty liberal on what it will accept, so if you are having trouble passing in a String or char[] array then I suspect there are bigger problems:

```
ANTLRInputStream() 
ANTLRInputStream(char[] data, int numberOfActualCharsInArray)
This is the preferred constructor for strings as no data is copied
ANTLRInputStream(InputStream input) 
ANTLRInputStream(InputStream input, int initialSize) 
ANTLRInputStream(InputStream input, int initialSize, int readChunkSize) 
ANTLRInputStream(Reader r) 
ANTLRInputStream(Reader r, int initialSize) 
ANTLRInputStream(Reader r, int initialSize, int readChunkSize) 
ANTLRInputStream(String input)
Copy data in string to a local char array
```

You ask for example so here is example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

// You're going to need to implement these based on the grammar you've created
import your.package.here.MyLangListener;
import your.package.here.MyLangTranslator;

// These are generated by ANTLR
import your.package.here.parser.LangLexer;
import your.package.here.LangParser;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "someInputBasedOnYourGrammarRules.lang";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            // Open the input file stream
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Create a CharStream that reads from standard input
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(fis);

            // Create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
            LangLexer lexer = new LangLexer(input);

            // Create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

            // Create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
            LangParser parser = new LangParser(tokens);

            // Begin parsing at rule prog
            ParseTree tree = parser.prog();

            // Close the input file
            fis.close();

            // Create a generic parse tree walker that can trigger callbacks
            ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
            // Walk the tree created during the parse, trigger callbacks
            walker.walk(new MyLangListener(), tree);
            System.out.println(); // print a \n after translation

            // Walk the tree again to translate to java
            walker.walk(new MyLangTranslator(), tree);

            // Print LISP-style tree
            //System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend that you use the ANTLR Maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

// You're going to need to implement these based on the grammar you've created
import your.package.here.MyLangListener;
import your.package.here.MyLangTranslator;

And why you used this two libs. Beacuse we haven't used them in string-input, and it works well.
Kindly look at our code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414352/taking-input-from-file-with-antlr
Though the errors are solved.

And what about Maven Plugin? Do we really need to use it?

Comment: It isn't critical to use the plugin, but it might be useful because it handles dependencies and organization.  MyLangListener and MyLangTranslator were extensions of base classes generated by ANTLR, and were used to override their default behavior (there really is no default behavior, just methods stubs with no body).  For every production rule, two methods were generated, an enter and exit method.  For example: void enterExpr(@NotNull LangParser.ExprContext ctx); and void exitExpr(@NotNull LangParser.ExprContext ctx);

Answer (score 3):

From Antlr 4.7 you can use CharStreams:

```
YourLexer lexer = new YourLexer(CharStreams.fromFileName("path/to/file.lang"));
```

Also, as of version 4.7 ANTLRFileStream is deprecated.